# How to insert an image into Google Forms?

Tags: images, google-forms

Last time I tried, you can't put an image into a Google form. Example, if you want people to vote on pictures, you can't do this. People use hacks to put in their own image. Am I missing something here? How can Google miss something like this?

Here are the options. There isn't one for inserting and image.
[image: Illustration for missing image]

Comment: please explain a little more

Comment: [Is copy pasting is not working? Copy the image and paste to the form. I am not sure. I have never tested that.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/444#444)

Comment: Copy and paste doesn't work.

Comment: Where have you seen this work?

Comment: `People use hacks to put in their own image` give us an example. You could try to insert HTML tags. But that'd hardly matter if the form data is not used in any html page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already implemented, see [Google Support](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839737):

> You can add an image to a question or an answer for multiple choice or checkbox questions.
>
> 1. In [Google Forms](https://forms.google.com/), open a form.
> 2. Click a question or answer.
> 3. To the right, click *Add image*.
> 4. Upload or choose an image.
> 5. Click **Select**.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to insert an image into Google forms currently.

Comment: This answer is outdated; it is possible now.