# Creating a troubleshooting tree in Google Forms, but it can't embed images or links

Tags: google-forms, bug-trackers

I tried creating a troubleshooting tree in Google Forms but appear to be [unable to embed either pictures](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7756/how-to-insert-an-image-into-google-forms) or links.

I wanted to create a tree wherein users get directed to different nodes with further suggestions and questions depending on their earlier answers, similar to (but hopefully more useful than) the Microsoft Windows troubleshooter.  If they are unable to resolve the problem themselves, I would like to receive an email or for a ticket or spreadsheet row to be created with the answers they provided.

I am the volunteer webmaster for a co-op preschool and receive many similar support requests, such as parents being unable to see the calendar for their child's class.  I created detailed guides that I can't get people to read.  Instead, everyone just emails me without giving me any of the details I need to solve the problem.

If this isn't possible to do in Google Forms, I'm open to other tools or services which can create tickets/emails as outlined above.

Other posts such as [building a support section to a website](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1213/what-web-apps-can-help-us-to-build-support-section-in-our-company-website) and [small business online support apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/what-is-a-good-small-business-online-support-application) are too bulky, and would prefer a lighter-weight solution if it's a no go in Google Forms.

Comment: Voted to close on the basis of a recommendation question. However, if you're up for it, would like to make an example of how this question can be better asked by editing to focus on how to make it work in Google Forms, and a line at the end saying you're open to using other apps if they can finish the job.

Comment: @eig, thanks for the feedback.  I'm new to webapps and it wasn't clear to me this type of question wasn't allowed (based on the previous questions I cite, for example).  Do you know if it would be appropriate in the webmaster site?

Comment: Not really as that form would be like a shopping question, which are off topic across the network. It would be better if you were trying to do this in Google Forms and just need that extra push.

Comment: @eig, the previous questions I cite were asking for recommendations?  Should those also have been closed, or have the rules been changed?  I'm not arguing, just trying to understand.  Thanks.

Comment: Voted to close those other questions as they were asking for recommendations. The rules have changed in that if the bulk of the question is such, it's not constructive. If the question was instead about how to solve a current problem, with the understanding that another service could do better and to allow such answers, that would be constructive

Comment: Edited it to be more of what is constructive. Options first on doing this in Google Forms, failing that, opening it up to suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [new Google Apps Scripts features](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/), especially [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service) - with a little programming, you can create a form that should fit your needs, and have the results posted to a Google Docs spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms now allows forms editors to insert images.

From [Add and edit questions, headers, images, videos, and page breaks](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839737?hl=en)

> Once you’ve created a form, you’re ready to start adding the questions you’d like to ask. If you’d like to give your form some structure, you can also add section headers and page breaks.
>
> ## Add questions, headers, and page breaks
>
> ...
>
> ### Add a section header
>
> If you'd like to divide your form into sections to make it easier to read and complete, add a section header. From the Insert menu, select *Section header*.
>   [image: Insert menu in Google Forms]
>
> For each section header, you can add both a section title and a section description.
>
> ### Add an image
>
> To add an image to your form, click the Insert menu, and select Image. Once you've uploaded the image, you can give it a title and specify what text will appear when someone hovers over the image.
>
> Images in forms aren't attached to or associated with form questions. You can change the position of an image by dragging it up or down in your form.